# Outh2: secure dynamically created resources from unauthoriesd access, allow only assigned user

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on spring boot and hibernate. For authentication i use oauth2.

I have an tree like hierarchy. In this hierarchy there are n node in each level and i need to assign each node directly to the department [department can further assign it to employee]  or to employee.

Each department and Employee have access type [view, update, create].

For this scenario i want to use `oauth2` but don't know is it possible in it or how to do it because node is created dynamically. and don't want to provide access based on particular role but based on user to whom it is assigned.

nodes are my resources and i want it properly secured from unauthorized access. but nodes are generated dynamically and as i know to avoid unauthorized access i should map `resource URL` with role. which is static. so is there any way or i should do it manually

Comment: Can you elaborate more on node & it's relation ship with your entity (like Department, Employee) & what are the security concerns for entity & node assign to it?

Comment: on each level there is 1-M  relationship between parent and child. 
between node and department 1-M. node and employee 1-M.and   department and employee 1-M.

Comment: nodes are my resources and i want it properly secured from unauthorized access. but nodes are generated dynamically and as i know to avoid unauthorized access i should map resorce url with role. which is static. so is there any way or i should do it manually

Comment: okay partially got what you are doing here. Can you give me url patterns using which any one is going to use employee or Department ? Give examples for each.

Comment: @PratikShah: i think i get the proper word for i need i think i need to implement ACL [access control list] a feature of spring security.